# How to GET HTML Label content via cURL in Bash?

Tags: html, bash, curl, get, label

I am trying to fetch my LTE router (which does not have SSH) for total month traffic to use in a dashboard.

I was able to mimic the login operation via Bash cURL by checking Chrome Developer Tools.

However, the data fetched contains only HTML Label IDs, not their value.

What should I change in order to get the actual values, like my browser does?

```
curl 'http://192.168.100.1/html/homeNetwork/traffic_statistic.html?t=1634412887718' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01' \
  -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'Authorization: Digest username="", realm="undefined", nonce="undefined", uri="/cgi/xml_action.cgi", response="be275e6f343de8b4234f4bbf0118acc4", qop=undefined, nc=0000001E, cnonce="e570dae1bf5033ed"' \
  -H 'Referer: http://192.168.100.1/index.html' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8,und;q=0.7,es;q=0.6,ja;q=0.5' \
  -H 'Cookie: CGISID=zuOetztYao9PqqntXxuRbtOWsbEx5BwBZdRhJjfMypARF; projectConfig=%5Bobject%20Object%5D' \
  --compressed \
  --insecure
```

The response:

```
[...]
<html>
<head>
[...]
</head>
<body>
<a href='#' class='help' onclick="getHelp('TrafficStatistics')">&nbsp;</a>
<label id="lt_commTraffic_TitleFromPowerOn" class="title"></label>
<label id="lt_commTraffic_StaticFromPowerOn"> </label>
<table width="100%" id="tableIpFilter" class="dataTbl10 example table-stripeclass:alternate" style="margin-top: 5px">
    <thead>
        <tr>         
            <th width="25%" id="lt_commTraffic_RxByte" ></th>       
            <th width="25%" id="lt_portTrigger_TxByte"></th>
            <th width="25%" id="lt_portTrigger_RxTxByte" ></th>              
            <th width="25%" id="lt_portTrigger_errorByte"> </th>            
        </tr>                
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbodyStaticFromPowerOn">
        <tr>         
            <td id="txtRxByteFromPower"></td>       
            <td id="txtTxByteFromPower"></td>
            <td id="txtRxTxByteFromPower"></td>   
            <td id="txtErrorByteFromPower"></td>           
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
[...]
</body>
</html>
```

All field/table values are blank, the only element present in the cURL response is their label IDs.
My browser displays the following:

[image: Browser display]

Comment: maybe there is some script in your html that subsequently requests that data and updates the html. Maybe check dev tools for other fetches like json files and try getting the information directly from there.

Comment: Does the LTE router have any sort of web API you could use instead of trying to scrape its GUI?